# BreezeController does not get the JObject (it is null)

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5, breeze

I have a javascript app that is using BreezeJs.

When I call `saveChanges`, the entities get converted to javascript and sent over the wire. (I confirmed this with fiddler.)

**But when I put a breakpoint in my Web Api Controller, the JObject for SaveChanges is null.**

I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is an example of how my controller is setup:

```
[BreezeController]
public class ShipmentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return dataAccess.Metadata();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Shipment> Shipments()
    {
        return dataAccess.Shipments();
    }


    //   This is what is NULL each time --------+
                                                |
                                                |
    [HttpPost]                                  V
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveJObject)
    {
        return dataAccess.SaveChanges(saveJObject);
    }

    //... Other stuff to get data
}
```

My queries to get data via the controller work fine.  So it is not a total failure scenario.

And as I said above, Fiddler shows valid JSON going over the wire.  But somehow the controller is not taking it.

My only guess is that I have several objects that I add to my client side breeze entities.  But I have done that as the [documentation](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/extending-entities.html) says you should and they show up in the `__unmapped` section of the object's JSONin fiddler.

**Does anyone have any ideas I can try to figure out why my Web Api controller is not getting the JObject?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you don't have navigation properties defined in your server-side model, you can create the navigation properties in the client-side metadata as long as you have the foreign key properties to work with:

```
    var childEntityType = metadataStore.getEntityType("MyChildEntity");
    childEntityType.addProperty(new breeze.NavigationProperty({
        name: "myParent",
        entityTypeName: "MyParentEntity:#My.Namespace",
        isScalar: true,
        associationName: "MyChildEntity_MyParentEntity",
        foreignKeyNames: ["myParentId"]
    }));
```

You should add these relationships immediately after retrieving the metadata from the server, and before creating any entities or performing any queries.

```
    entityManager.fetchMetadata().then(function () {
        patchMetadata(entityManager.metadataStore); // add missing navigations
    });
```

With the navigation property added, Breeze will automatically hook up your related entities upon query, so you don't need to create unmapped properties.

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, my database is old and so I am working off views to the data.  This means that I can't put in Foreign Keys into my database level model.

The Entity Framework model also does not have any associations.

So, I manually constructed these relationships on the client side by adding entities and unmapped properties to other entities.  (So in my example above, Shipment would have a `OriginId: int` in the actual entity, but I would add an unmapped property of `Origin`.  But `Origin` was itself an entity that I had retrieved as reference data.)

Turns out that is not supported:  https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/85

When I changed my model so that I did not have entities as unmapped entities and the `SaveChanges` worked correctly.